# Unable to delete a Tensorflow training job on google cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, object-detection-api

I have created 2 Tensorflow Object Detection jobs on Google Cloud. I cancelled one of them and the other has failed. I have tried looking for ways to delete these jobs but am unable to do so. Is there any way I can delete the jobs? Also, will I be billed for these jobs even though they are cancelled/stopped?

[image]

Comment: I actually tried to cancel a job using the following command
`gcloud ai-platform jobs cancel <job name>` . However, I get an error saying 
`(gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.cancel) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: name Error: Cannot cancel an already completed job.`
So does this mean I won't incur any charges for the failed job?

Comment: You will not be billed for cancelled or stopped jobs.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: To be clear, you will be billed for the consumed compute up to the point where the job was cancelled/stopped. But the billing stops afterwards

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/pricing

Comment: Did you try with the beta command to [jobs cancel](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ai-platform/jobs/cancel) . As is mentioned earlier the management operations provided by AI Platform are available [free of charge](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/pricing#free_operations_for_managing_your_resources)

Comment: I actually found out later that I won't be billed for a canceled job(since it is not actually running anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you cannot currently *delete* GCP AI Platform jobs.  The API only describes [four operations](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/managing-models-jobs#managing_jobs) for jobs: `create`, `cancel`, `get`, and `list`.  No option is available in the UI either.

Jobs in the cancelled and stopped state will not accrue additional charges.